# Image color bug?

Tags: ios, swift, image, colors

I'd like to generate this cool like on an UIImage using the code I've added below. **But there seems to be a crazy bug in relation to the color**:

So I'd like my function to draw lines to the image with a given RGB value (in my case `r:76, g:255, b:0` to get this green look) as it's color:

[image: img1]

But the code I'm using **just colors the image kind of magenta instead of green**:

[image: img2]

Please have a look at my code:

```
func colorImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let color = RGBA32(red: 76, green: 255, blue: 0, alpha: 255)
    let img: CGImage = image.cgImage!
    let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: img.width, height: img.height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4 * img.width, space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)!
    context.draw(img, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: img.width, height: img.height))
    let binaryData = context.data!.bindMemory(to: RGBA32.self, capacity: img.width * img.height)
    for y in stride(from: 0, through: img.height, by: 10) {
        for x in 0..<img.width {
            let pixel = (y*img.width) + x
            binaryData[pixel] = color
        }
    }
    let output = context.makeImage()!
    return UIImage(cgImage: output, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
}
```

---

```
struct RGBA32: Equatable {
    private var color: UInt32
    init(red: UInt8, green: UInt8, blue: UInt8, alpha: UInt8) {
        let red   = UInt32(red)
        let green = UInt32(green)
        let blue  = UInt32(blue)
        let alpha = UInt32(alpha)
        color = (red << 24) | (green << 16) | (blue << 8) | (alpha << 0)
    }
    static func ==(lhs: RGBA32, rhs: RGBA32) -> Bool {
        return lhs.color == rhs.color
    }
}
```

Tbh I'm absolutely clueless why this issue appears - so any help how to fix this would be very appreciated. Thanks `:)`

Comment: Don't you think the color shown looks like r:255,g:0,b:255,a:76. You know iOS runs on little-endian CPUs?

Comment: And it seems really strange to be assigning a `struct` to each pixel instead of the `UInt32` value contained in the `struct`. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Would you be so kind to share some code about your ideas? @rmaddy

Comment: Instead of manipulating the pixels, just draw the original image into an image graphics context, draw the lines onto that, and extract the resulting image. Done.

Comment: So the code on top was just an example snippet - **I absolutely realize that "drawing lines onto an UIView by manipulating it's pixels" is completely the wrong way** but in other parts I of "manipulating pixels" my _(not shared)_ code came to this color-issue - **Thats the reason why I asked you guys and added a simple example to show the issue in a obvious way :)** @matt

Comment: Sure that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RGBA is a confusing word. It is not clear if R is the most significant byte in the 32-bit data or the first byte in the 4-byte memory region.

But with your `bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue`,
R takes the first place and G, B, and then Alpha last.

In little-endian representation of `UInt32`, R for the least significant byte.

Try this version of `RGBA`:

```
struct RGBA32: Equatable {
    private var color: (red: UInt8, green: UInt8, blue: UInt8, alpha: UInt8)
    init(red: UInt8, green: UInt8, blue: UInt8, alpha: UInt8) {
        color = (red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }
    static func ==(lhs: RGBA32, rhs: RGBA32) -> Bool {
        return lhs.color == rhs.color
    }
}
```

(Memory allocations of Swift structs or tuples are not clearly defined, but the above code works as expected.)

Comment: If the original problem was due to byte ordering, it's probably a bad solution that still relies on specific byte ordering. There are proper functions that help you deal with host byte ordering so the code will work on both real iOS devices and the simulator.

Comment: @rmaddy, seems you are mistaking something. With the OP's `CGContext` settings, 4 color components R, G, B, A are ordered as specified, independent of the endianness.

Comment: I get that the context expects the bytes in a specific order. The problem is with the memory layout of the data in the `struct`. If it weren't a byte order issue then why did the OP's original code have an issue? And unless I'm mistaken (which I certainly am likely to be), this answer also depends on the internal memory ordering of the 4 values in the tuple of the struct. Has this answer been testing on both a real device and a simulator?

Comment: @rmaddy, yes, it's a problem of memory layout, but it's not a problem of _host byte ordering_ or endianness. The OP's original code was endianness-dependent and misordered. My answer depends on memory layout, but endianness-independent. The actual device? Try by yourself. (Though, currently both iOSs, actual device and simulator, are little-endian.)